# Docker-Compose NGINX/uWSGI/Flask bind mount issue

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

For some reason when I update the "app.py" file on the host computer it will not update in the browser (localhost). The only way it will update is if I shutdown the container, rebuild, and restart. Cant figure out what I am missing here?

Here are a few of the relevant parts. You can see the whole code on my github

https://github.com/longfellowone/Docker-Flask-NGINX-uWSGI

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── sock.sock
│   └── uwsgi.ini
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   └── uwsgi_params
└── README.md
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    web: 
      build: ./app
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./app
          target: /src
      command: uwsgi --ini ./uwsgi.ini

    nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/
        - type: bind
          source: ./app/
          target: /tmp
```

**nginx.conf**

```
    sendfile off;

    upstream app { server unix:/tmp/sock.sock; }

    server {

        location / { try_files $uri @web; }

        location @web {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass app;
        }
```

**/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:latest

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /src/
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]

module = app:app

socket = sock.sock
chmod-socket = 666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: solution was to add to **uwsgi.ini**

```
"py-autoreload = 1"
```